# Return char array C

Tags: c, return, chararray

I have a function that makes a string with a certain number of #. String is stored as in char array (at list I think this is it... I'm new to C). This string is generated inside a function called blocks. I want to know how to return it so I can display it with `printf("Someting Something %s", bricks)` Do I have to change data type of ma string to char or how do I change the code to work?

```
int main(void)
{
    char hashes = blocks(3);
}

char blocks(int n)
{
    // string in which I will store data
    char line[] = ""; 
    int max = n + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        // n times # is appended to char array line
        char brick[] = "#";
        strcat(line, brick);
    }
    return line;
}
```

I want to know how to return string or array  `###` and store it in variable hashes.

Comment: @klutt this dupe does not cover all problems of this "code"

Comment: The main point is that C doesn't handle strings as a native type like java does. The line `char line[]=""` just allocate one byte of memory set to `'\0` (end of C string). Really you may want have a look to a C book/tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Plenty problems.

1. `line` is not long enough to accommodate additional characters added by `strcat`. Actually, it can only accommodate null terminating character
2. You cant return the pointer to the local variable as this variable stops existing when the function returns.
3. Your function returns the `char` not `char *` pointer. So the pointer is being converted to `int`
4. `hashes` is assigned a nonsense value as per p3

I think you need to start from the C book.